# Ubuntu 20.04 - USB-C to DisplayPort and issues with kernel log

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport, usb-c

I'm trying to connect a DisplayPort monitor on a laptop through a USB-C connector. However, it does not work. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, `uname -a`:

```
5.8.0-50-generic #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 21:46:35 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

also, doing a `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`:

```
kernel: [48790.073284] usb usb4-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
```

Questions:

1. is there anything that I can do to get the external monitor working? I'm googling around since yesterday but haven't found a clear path to follow
2. any way to stop or silence that log warning? it does not allow me to reboot normally and I have to shut down the laptop brutally using the power button.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does your laptop's usb-c port support display output because many laptop have usb-c port but doesn't support display output Give more information about ur laptop

Comment: how? is a company laptop, provided to me as a workstation. the manufacturer is https://www.pcspecialist.it/, looks like they have a forum support, tried to register but keeps to return me an error. 
Is there any command that provide details on any usb interface, including the information you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

All of a sudden same issue here. Worked last week. Somehow stopped working. Only thing I can think of is some Ubuntu update, or plugging in another monitor messed up some config.
Not a lot of resources online on how to fix this. Any tips would be appreciated.

Cheers!